# Understanding the concept of mass in a matching algorithm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Suppose we have two finite sets $\mathcal{K}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\gamma_K\geq 0$, $\gamma_Q\geq 0$

The cardinality of $\mathcal{K}$ is $[n \exp(\gamma_{K})]$ and the cardinality of $\mathcal{Q}$ is $[n \exp(\gamma_{Q})]$, where$[x]$ denotes the value of $x$ rounded to the nearest integer.

For example: impose $n=1$, $\gamma_K=1$, $\gamma_Q=1.4$. Then $\mathcal{K}$ has three elements and $\mathcal{Q}$ has four elements, e.g., 
$$
\mathcal{K}\equiv \{1,2,3\}
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{Q}\equiv \{1,2,3,4\}
$$

---

Suppose that each element of $\mathcal{K}$ denotes a man, and each element of $\mathcal{Q}$ denotes a woman. Consider an algorithm pairing (according to some optimisation rules) the men in $\mathcal{K}$ with the woman in $\mathcal{Q}$. The output of the algorithm are some couples such that: (I) if $i\in \mathcal{K}$ is paired with $j\in \mathcal{Q}$, then $i$ and $j$ cannot be paired with other elements; (II) individuals on both sides can remain single.

Continuing the example above, a possible output of the algorithm is $(1,2), (2,3), (3,0), (0,1), (0,4)$, where $(i,j)$ denotes the couple formed by $i\in \mathcal{K}$ and $j\in \mathcal{Q}$, $(i,0)$ denotes that $i\in \mathcal{K}$ is single,   $(0,j)$ denotes that $j\in \mathcal{Q}$ is single.

---

Question:

1) I want to write down what is the total **mass** of individuals. Some notes I am studying say that it is equal to $$\exp(\gamma_K)+\exp(\gamma_Q)$$ Why?

2) The same notes say that the **mass** of pairs matched by the algorithm (with the inclusion of singles) is between $$\exp(\max\{\gamma_K, \gamma_Q\})$$ and $$\exp(\gamma_K)+\exp(\gamma_Q)$$

Why?

I think I am not getting why the mass of men is $\exp(\gamma_K)$ and why the mass of women is $\exp(\gamma_Q)$. If I clarify this, then 1) and 2) become clearer.

Comment: what is the 'mass' and why is this taged as 'probability'?

Comment: "Some notes I am studying" is not a sufficient reference

Comment: Are you sure about $(0,4)$ in your output example? Note that preceding that is $(0,3)$ which means that $0\in\mathcal K$ is already matched with $3\in\mathcal Q$, when you successively match it with $4\in\mathcal Q$.

Comment: Maybe this is extracted from a wider context, but as you write it, notation seems needlessly complicated. Instead of $[n\exp\gamma_X]$ for $X=\mathcal K,\mathcal Q$ you could simply use two integers, say $k$ and $q$.

Comment: $(3,0)$ means that man $3$ is single. $(0,4)$ means that woman $4$ is single.